# HP- ALM Installation error - QAIAD.dll has no digital signature or the publisher is untrusted

Tags: hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I have installed HP ALM 11.52 on windows server 2008 r2 for learning purpose. I have used sql sever 2008 and iis 7. I have installed and configured the ALM successfully to use on local machine. Now i can login into the site administration using valid credentials but I can't login into the site as user. while login it's show me this error

Following client components were not downloaded successfully.
1. QAIAD.dll
This file has no digital signature or the publilsher is untrusted.
Close all connections to server and try again.

I have searched the internet and found some solutions like,
put **localhost:8080/qcbin** into trusted site and lower the security level in IE
Disable the check for valid digital sign, valid publisher certi, valid server certi under advanced tab in IE version 10,
cleared the local temp data. And Run the IE as Administrator
Registed Hp client from tool but same error.

But all these didn't work for me. I have wasted almost a day to solve this but found no solution.
So, please help me solve this issue.

Please check the attached snapshot of issue.
[problem image](http://screencast.com/t/oyvqVfq1Ilx)

Answer (score 0):

Append to the end of the URL the following:

`?cancelcrlcheck=true`